# HTML Simple Dom parser - How to get a specific text out?

Tags: html, dom

Hi there i am currently using PHPSimpleDomParser to get date from other pages source.
Here you can check more about this parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

I have no problem parsing dom elements such as `<div></div>`,`<img>` and other simple HTML elements.

Right now i want to get data text which is stored in Javascript which can be seen in the source of the page.

Here is the sample of exact text which i want to get:

```
"SizeVarId":"37800208195"
"SizeVarId":"37800208215"
"SizeVarId":"37800208235"
"SizeVarId":"37800208175"
```

As you can understand i want to select all `"SizeVarId":"RandomNumbers"` and get the number inside the second quotes.

Is it posible and how i can get it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get this using Javascript or your PHP parser? Are these lines inside an element? Where are they on the page? Please provide some more details :).

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.sportsdirect.com/nike-manchester-united-home-shirt-2013-2014-rooney-10-junior-378002?colcode=37800208 Get out the source of this page and search for `"SizeVarId"`

Answer (score 1):

Its easy if you know how to work with Regex. Here I assume this Text is assigned to a variable in a java-script.

```
var text = '"SizeVarId":"37800208195""SizeVarId":"37800208215"';
var patt = /\"([0-9]+)\"/;
var results = patt.exec(text);
console.log(results);
```

This is how you do it in PHP

```
$url = "http://page-you-want-to.fetch";
$ch = new curl_init($url);
curl_set_opt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURN_TRANSFER,true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match_all('/\"SizeVarId\":\"([0-9]+)\"/',$data,$matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: your question is not clear. You want to fetch data/source of a page and the parse the text in PHP?

Comment: Yes that's it exactly